# Use Ansible vault password to encrypt zip file

Tags: ansible

I have been given an Ansible playbook that aims to password protect a zip file.
(Part of) the playbook looks like this:

```
- name: Create and encrypt zipfile
  vars:
    zipPW: !vault |
      $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
      64656637643264313764633665363234393239346230643936393864313337313030613461326639
      3538303634303365373637633761306133333266393331630a336436383534323264376537653564
      32393162353730373335303733663463333764616438643762653330616431353162326238663564
      3163306336313931660a313530343935643366663433346231386638353932313936366538643664
  shell: "zip -jr /tmp/pit/{{hostvars[inventory_hostname]['gzipoutfile']['stdout']}}.zip /tmp/pit/{{hostvars[inventory_hostname]['gzipoutfile']['stdout']}} -P {{zipPW}}"
  register: zipped
- debug:
    msg: "{{zipped}}
```

So they are trying to pass the vault password to the zip command for the -P option.

This does not seem to work.
When running the playbook, I get:

```
"Attempting to decrypt but no vault secrets found"}
```

As far as I understand Ansible vault this means I need to provide a password to be able to use the vault password, but I could be wrong.
Having to provide a password seems useless if you want to automate things. If I put the password in a file, I'm just as vulnerable as when I would not password encrypt the zip file.

Is this way of trying to use a vault password even possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Ansible has [various ways](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/vault_guide/vault_managing_passwords.html#storing-and-accessing-vault-passwords) to provide the vault password.

- files - can be protected by filesystem permissions
- scripts - can access other vaults, decode/decrypt the vault password stored somewhere else

But all boil down to the same problem, at some point you need to provide something to decrypt the password, which makes it difficult for automation processes. It's up to you to decide where you want to store a plain text secret to decrypt the vault passwords.